# Displaying data from api errors on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api that displays the current price of bitcoin that I want to display on my page.
I call the api and set the `data` state to it with the following code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://blockchain.info/ticker") // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
      .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        setData(resp);
      });
     
  }, []);
```

This works as shown in the console.log() statement.

 Then I display it with the following
`<header className="App-header">Bitcoin is {data.USD.buy}  </header>`
The odd thing is that is works, until the page is refreshed and I get a error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'buy' of undefined`

My original thought was that the api call was not completed before the component rendered, so I added an if statement.

```
if (data !== null) {
return ( 
  <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">Bitcoin is {data.USD.buy}  </header>
    </div>
)} 
else return <h1>aaa</h1>
};
```

So far though the issue persists. I am rather inexperienced with api calls and using hooks, so I am thinking the error is there.
The full code is: [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/bitcoinTracker/blob/main/src/App.js)

 Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is data contains exactly?

Comment: https://blockchain.info/ticker

Comment: Yeah, but what do you get? Try console.log(data) when it's not null to see what you get.

Comment: I do get the data, and it does display correctly the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example, initial value should be null

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kvpzxm?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: It looks like that was the issue. Not setting the initial state correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I edited some of the code you showed us, and now the data is displayed :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch("https://blockchain.info/ticker");
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">Bitcoin is {data.USD.buy}</header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sum up of what I've done :

1. Use of async/await to handle the asynchronous of fetching datas
2. Removing the then, but you can put them again and format the datas like you want